# ¿Cómo crear una macro para la combinación Alt+R?

Tags: javascript, macros, autohotkey

Estoy haciendo el script para jugar, por lo que solo necesito que se repita la tecla que estoy oprimiendo, como lo hago aquí con la tecla 0 y este repite que oprimí la tecla en las 3 ventanas abiertas (estoy haciendo multiboxing).

```
~0::
KeyWait 0
IfWinActive, World of Warcraft
{
  ControlSend,, 0, ahk_id %wowid1%
  ControlSend,, 0, ahk_id %wowid2%
  ControlSend,, 0, ahk_id %wowid3%
  Return
}
```

Ahora, estoy intentando hacer lo mismo con la combinación Alt+R pero me genera un error. Estaba intentando de la siguiente forma:

```
~!R::
KeyWait !R
IfWinActive, World of Warcraft
{
  ControlSend,, !R, ahk_id %wowid1%
  ControlSend,, !R, ahk_id %wowid2%
  ControlSend,, !R, ahk_id %wowid3%
  Return
}
```

Answer (score 0):

para la persona que desee realizar esto, se puuede hacer de la siguiente manera (pongo como ejemplo la combinacion de teclas alt+r)

```
~Alt & R::
Keywait Alt, R
IfWinActive, World of Warcraft
{
ControlSend,, {AltDown}R{AltUp}, ahk_id %wowid1% //Aca esta el cambio, basicamente se "presiona el boton, oprime la tecla y lo suelta"
ControlSend,, {AltDown}R{AltUp}, ahk_id %wowid2% 
ControlSend,, {AltDown}R{AltUp}, ahk_id %wowid3% //Y lo repite en 3 ventanas
Return
}
```

Esta manera es la que encontre que es mas funcional para mi requerimiento (replicar la misma accion 3 veces en ventanas distintas).

Comment: ¿Puedes editar la respuesta contando un poco cuáles fueron los cambios que hiciste y para qué sirven? Por cierto, la pregunta era sobre Alt+R, estaría bien que la pregunta y la respuesta coincidan.

Comment: `ALT + v`, usa el caracter __`__ al inicio y final del texto.